# In Kentico 8 for the Uni Selector form control what are legal Object Type values

Tags: kentico

I am trying to set up a form control in a document type for Kentico where there would be a list of all documents on the site of a given document type.

I can get the document list if i set "Object Type" to cms.document

As I understand this then pulls the date from the CMS_Document table.  Unfortunately that table does not have the ClassID field to filter by document type.

I instead tried setting Object Type to cms.tree, but i get an error
Object type 'cms.tree' not found
The same thing happens when I try to use my own document type.  As I understand the documentation I should be able to pass in any value here from CMS_Class database table, but it is not working.  What are legal types that I can use in that field, and how can I filter my list down by document type?

Answer (score 3):

Uniselector:
Use `ObjectType=cms.document` and set where condition to something like:

```
DocumentNodeID IN (SELECT NodeID FROM CMS_Tree WHERE NodeClassID = 
(SELECT ClassID FROM CMS_Class WHERE ClassName='CMS.MenuItem'))
```

Then adjust ClassName you want to filter and add where condition for NodeSiteID if you want to filter by site.

API:
If you need to get a list of all documents on a given site just use the `DocumentHelper.GetDocuments(...)` and use className parameter to specify document type. Don't bother with retrieving objects of a given ObjectType (I guess you are using `CMSObjectHelper`).

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Working+with+documents+in+the+API

Comment: I am actually doing this through the UI.  I have a document type where i need to select another document type of a correct type